# Removing duplicate phrases from a bunch of text files?

Tags: duplicates

INPUT:
The text files contain text from a news website but without the html tags.
Some of the sentences don't have full stops. Some sentences are made up of phrases scrapped from navigation links joined in one line.

DESIRED OUTPUT:
Same text files but without the duplicate phrases.

Possible approach:
First reduce the text file sizes by removing the stop words, remove duplicate text files(if any), then apply the magic from here

Thanks in advance

Comment: QUESTION: what have you tried? do you have some code to show us?

Comment: With regards to duplicating have not gotten a good lead. Am new to text mining but using rapidminer have been able removing stop words and stemming. From there options available seem to be creating word lists from vectors. So kind of deadend I think. Any happy to attempt any leads. Thanks